# Dynamic Form Fields

Tags: forms, dynamic

I'm not exactly sure what to call the thing i am searching for.  If I knew what to call it I might find the answer, so if you have an answer to my question or even know what I can search for that would be very helpful.

I am trying to create a simple php form that has standard fields like name, email, etc.  I want to add an event type field that is a drop down with pre-selected values (i.e wedding, birthday, etc).  Once they select a particular event I want other options to appear.

For exmaple they would select wedding and then date, venue, etc would then come up.  If they selected birthday, then different additional options would appear.

Does anyone know the technical term for this, or where I can find a tutorial on it?  Does it require ajax or jquery or something else?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with jQuery. It sounds like you want more than just dynamic `select` (drop down) inputs. You could check [this blog post](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/) out, but that really only covers the drop down fields.

It sounds like you want something fairly custom. You could separate your form into the individual steps and hide many of the fields to start. With jQuery, you can apply event handlers to fire functions when something is selected and then the function would determine what fields to show.

You don't really need to use AJAX unless you need the options (specifically drop downs) to contain options which are pulled from a dynamic source (e.g. a database).

Comment: I do want more then drop downs, as those are pretty simple.  The hide fields and event handlers sounds about right.  Thanks for the answer, now I have a place to start looking for a tutorial.  Thanks again.